# Why does AspectJ @Around advice execute twice?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I have the following AspectJ example that I've done as a "hello world" style proof of concept. The advising code in the `StyleAspect` seems to execute twice even though the actual code in `SomeClass` only executes once (as required).

Here's the code:

Firstly, an annotation called WithStyle:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface WithStyle {  
}
```

Then, an aspect that intercepts any code with the @WithStyle annotation

```
@Aspect
public class StyleAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(WithStyle)")
    public Object doItWithStyle(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Doing it in style...");
        Object result = pjp.proceed();
        System.out.println("Done");
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

and finally, some code with the annotation

```
public class SomeClass {
    
    @WithStyle
    public void doIt() {
        System.out.println("I'm doing it....");
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ AspectJTest ---
Doing it in style...
Doing it in style...
I'm doing it....
Done
Done
```

So it seems as if while the code itself only executes once, the code in the aspect is getting executed twice.

Here's the calling code:

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        someClass.doIt();
    }
}
```

and for completeness, I'm including the pom with the AspectJ plugin config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ie.philb</groupId>
    <artifactId>AspectJTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.java.target>1.8</project.build.java.target>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>       <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>  <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
      
</project>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `around()` *advice* is intercepting both the `call` and `execution` join points of the method annotated with `@WithStyle` (*i.e.,* `doIt()`). If you add a `System.out.println(pjp);` to your aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class StyleAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(WithStyle) ") 
    public Object doItWithStyle(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(pjp);
        System.out.println("Doing it in style...");
        Object result;
        try{
            result = pjp.proceed();
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

you would get the following output:

```
call(public void SomeClass.doIt()) <----
Doing it in style...
execution(public void SomeClass.doIt()) <----
Doing it in style...
I'm doing it....
Done
Done
```

You can clearly see that the join points `call` and `execution` of method `SomeClass.doIt()` are being intercepted by the `around` *advice* `doItWithStyle`.

From the interception of the `call`, the `around` *advice* is *weaving* the code as follows:

```
// around advice code  before the pjp.proceed();
someClass.doIt(); // during the pjp.proceed();
// around advice code  after the pjp.proceed();
```

consequently:

```
 System.out.println("Doing it in style...");.
 someClass.doIt();
 System.out.println("Done");
```

From the execution:

```
@WithStyle
public void doIt() {
    // around advice code  before the pjp.proceed();
    System.out.println("I'm doing it....");
  // around advice code  after the pjp.proceed();
}
```

consequently:

```
@WithStyle
public void doIt() {
    System.out.println("Doing it in style...");
    System.out.println("I'm doing it....");
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

resulting in the output:

```
Doing it in style... 
Doing it in style...
I'm doing it....
Done
Done
```

Now, if you want to avoid the `around` *advice* from intercepting both the `call` and the `execution` of the method `doIt()`. You need to further restrict the join points intercepted by your `around` *advice*. To just intercept the method `call`, you can do:

```
 @Around("@annotation(WithStyle) && call(* *(..))")
```

for the method `execution`:

```
@Around("@annotation(WithStyle) && execution(* *(..))")
```

You can further restrict the join points being intercepted based on the number of arguments of the method, its returning type, name, and so on, by tuning the signature of the `call` or `execution` pointcuts.